# Not able to get all applications in "Choose an app to run" popUp while integrate action extension in application

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8, ios10

I am working on action extension integration in application using this Link http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Creating_an_iOS_8_Action_Extension

I am not able to follow "Testing the Extension" step in an application.

Problem is that I am not getting Notes application in "Choose an app to run " popup.

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you testing on the simulator? I don't believe the Notes app is on there. Try a device instead.

Comment: let me try in device, Now i am testing in stimulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to get "Choose an app to run" popUp after run application on a device.